# Python 2.7 GUI using Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm totally new to Python and GUI. I am trying to create a simple GUI using Tkinter which has two file browser options and a command button.

When I try to click on the first browse button and select the file, the file name is displayed in both text boxes. Similarly, when I click on the second button, the new file name is displayed in both text boxes. Please correct me where I'm going wrong. I tried much to fix but in vein. Also, Please pour in suggestions to improve my coding to reduce the LOC for such a simple GUI.

[Issue Sceenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDFQJ.jpg)

```
import os
import Tkinter
import tkFileDialog
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
from Tkinter import *

file_path_1 = ''
file_path_2 = ''

#~~~~ FUNCTIONS~~~~

def open_rules_file():
  global file_path_1
  filename1 = askopenfilename()
  file_path_1 = os.path.abspath(filename1)
  print file_path_1
  entry1.delete(0, END)
  entry1.insert(0, file_path_1)

def open_src_file():
  global file_path_2
  filename2 = askopenfilename()
  file_path_2 = os.path.abspath(filename2)
  print file_path_2
  entry2.delete(0, END)
  entry2.insert(0, file_path_2)

#~~~~~~ GUI ~~~~~~~~

root = Tk()
root.title('MY GUI')
root.geometry("1000x300+250+100")

mf = Frame(root)
mf.pack()
f1 = Frame(mf, width=600, height=250)
f1.pack(fill=X)
f2 = Frame(mf, width=600, height=250)
f2.pack()
f3 = Frame(mf, width=600, height=250)
f3.pack()

file_path_1 = StringVar
file_path_2 = StringVar

Label(f1,text="Select Rules Sheet (xls)").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='e')
entry1 = Entry(f1, width=70, textvariable=file_path_1)
entry1.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=2,pady=2,sticky='we',columnspan=25)
Button(f1, text="Browse1", command=open_rules_file).grid(row=1, column=27, sticky='ew', padx=8, pady=4)

Label(f2,text="Select COBOL Source   ").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='e')
entry2 = Entry(f2, width=70, textvariable=file_path_2)
entry2.grid(row=2,column=1,padx=2,pady=2,sticky='we',columnspan=25)
Button(f2, text="Browse2", command=open_src_file).grid(row=2, column=27, sticky='ew', padx=8, pady=4)

Button(f3, text='Quit', command=f3.quit).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem on my machine.

Comment: I have udpated my post to include screenshot. kindly check the same.

Comment: I'm also unable to reproduce the problem, works fine for me.

Comment: Why are you using StringVar in your code ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating object of StringVar class you have just assigned class to those variable

```
import os
import Tkinter
import tkFileDialog
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
from Tkinter import *

file_path_1 = ''
file_path_2 = ''

#~~~~ FUNCTIONS~~~~

def open_rules_file():
  global file_path_1
  filename1 = askopenfilename()
  file_path_1 = os.path.abspath(filename1)
  print file_path_1
  entry1.delete(0, END)
  entry1.insert(0, file_path_1)

def open_src_file():
  global file_path_2
  filename2 = askopenfilename()
  file_path_2 = os.path.abspath(filename2)
  print file_path_2
  entry2.delete(0, END)
  entry2.insert(0, file_path_2)

#~~~~~~ GUI ~~~~~~~~

root = Tk()
root.title('MY GUI')
root.geometry("1000x300+250+100")

mf = Frame(root)
mf.pack()
f1 = Frame(mf, width=600, height=250)
f1.pack(fill=X)
f2 = Frame(mf, width=600, height=250)
f2.pack()
f3 = Frame(mf, width=600, height=250)
f3.pack()

##Instead of creating object of that class you have just assigned class to those variable
file_path_1 = StringVar()
file_path_2 = StringVar()

Label(f1,text="Select Rules Sheet (xls)").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='e')
entry1 = Entry(f1, width=70, textvariable=file_path_1)
entry1.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=2,pady=2,sticky='we',columnspan=25)
Button(f1, text="Browse1", command=open_rules_file).grid(row=1, column=27, sticky='ew', padx=8, pady=4)

Label(f2,text="Select COBOL Source   ").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='e')
entry2 = Entry(f2, width=70, textvariable=file_path_2)
entry2.grid(row=2,column=1,padx=2,pady=2,sticky='we',columnspan=25)
Button(f2, text="Browse2", command=open_src_file).grid(row=2, column=27, sticky='ew', padx=8, pady=4)

Button(f3, text='Quit', command=f3.quit).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Entry widget, you don't need textvariable at all. Just remove them and use widget's own methods.

```
def open_rules_file():
  filename1 = askopenfilename()
  print(filename1)
  entry1.delete(0, END)
  entry1.insert(0, filename1)

def open_src_file():
  filename2 = askopenfilename()
  print(filename2)
  entry2.delete(0, END)
  entry2.insert(0, filename2)

#~~~~~~ GUI ~~~~~~~~

root = Tk()
root.title('MY GUI')
root.geometry("1000x300+250+100")

mf = Frame(root)
mf.pack()

f1 = Frame(mf, width=600, height=250)
f2 = Frame(mf, width=600, height=250)
f3 = Frame(mf, width=600, height=250)

f1.pack(fill=X)
f2.pack()
f3.pack()

Label(f1,text="Select Rules Sheet (xls)").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='e')
entry1 = Entry(f1, width=70)
entry1.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=2,pady=2,sticky='we',columnspan=25)
Button(f1, text="Browse1", command=open_rules_file).grid(row=1, column=27, sticky='ew', padx=8, pady=4)

Label(f2,text="Select COBOL Source   ").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='e')
entry2 = Entry(f2, width=70)
entry2.grid(row=2,column=1,padx=2,pady=2,sticky='we',columnspan=25)
Button(f2, text="Browse2", command=open_src_file).grid(row=2, column=27, sticky='ew', padx=8, pady=4)

Button(f3, text='Quit', command=f3.quit).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
root.mainloop()
```

But if you really insist on using it, you can change value of `StringVar` by using `file_path_1.set("your value")`.

Your usage right now (`file_path_1 = "value"`) changes `file_path_1` to a plain string.

```
def open_rules_file():
  var.set(askopenfilename())

var = StringVar()
entry1 = Entry(f1, width=70, textvariable = var)
```